# Why Dart extension methods don't work for Image class

Tags: flutter, image, dart, extension-methods

Hi people I'm facing a simple problem, I have this small code and doesn't work

```
extension ImageExt on Image {
  static Image base64(String encode, {double? width, double? height}) {
  final reserveWord = 'base64,';
  final codePart = encode.contains(reserveWord)
    ? encode.substring(encode.indexOf(reserveWord) + reserveWord.length)
    : encode;

  return Image.memory(base64Decode(codePart), width: width, height: height);
}
```

}

And when I try to use the autocomplete of VSCode, the method doesn't exist.
[image: VSCode]

I include at the top of the file the import statement pointing at the correct file where my extension is defined. So I can't figure out what's wrong, please any help here will be appreciated. At the same file exists other extensions in these cases to String and Map types and work fine.

Comment: It seems strange to put a static in an extension; why not make it a top level function? This is a similar philosophy to: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `base64` on `ImageExt` like `ImageExt.base64('...', width: 24, height: 24);`. Currently static members on extensions are only accessible in the namespace of the extension itself (in this case ImageExt not Image).

You might be interested in reading this feature request submitted a while back on the dart language repo asking for static extension methods to be changed to support this. https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723

Comment: All the more reason to make it a top level function. See Remi's comment in the issue: "I do agree that it doesn't make sense to use the static keyword on a generic on."

Comment: Seems like Remi might rewrite it as a factory constructor (if it was supported) rather than a static member (based on his full comment), but a top level function would be a perfectly reasonable way to approach this as well.

Comment: @RichardHeap That's what I did in which I got some response. Thanks a lot